# Where can I find User/pass for SQL in PrestaShop website filesystem?

Tags: mysql, prestashop

I have just inherited a website from a client who has no idea what their usernames and passwords are for anything.  I had to fight the hosts to get access to her files but they are being quite unco-operative in terms of helping me access her database.

I know in other CMS the user/pass for the database is hardcoded in a particular file on the filesystem, but I've never used PrestaShop before and don't know where to start looking.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prestashop has pretty good [online documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/dashboard.action) and below is a snippet taken from the documentation for version 1.6 and I'm sure that nothing major has changed since 1.6 > 1.7 regarding the database settings file.

> [SOURCE](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting-Regeneratingapasswordmanually)
>
> There are situations where nothing happens when you request a new
>   password, and it doesn't work. There can be a number of reasons why
>   this would happen, but the important thing is to be able to log in
>   again.
>
> This is will require you to access your database, using phpMyAdmin for
>   instance.
>
> You will have to follow the following procedure:
>
> Open the `/config/settings.inc.php` file, from your shop's root
>   directory

Comment: Perfect!  I am in straight away.  Thank you very much Simon :)